Covering a spherical cap with smaller spherical caps. How to get the number of caps knowing caps density
Consider the spherical cap
$$
\mathcal{S} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | \|x\| = 1, x^T \cdot e_1 \geq t \}
$$
where $e_1$ is the first column in the unit matrix and $t \in (0,1)$. Can we compute a minimum number of spherical caps needed to cover $\mathcal{S}$?  Asume the spherical caps needed are defined as follows: for $v \in \mathcal{S}$
$$
\mathcal{S}' = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n | \|x\| = 1, x^T\cdot v \geq u\}
$$ where $u \in (t,1)$.
Edit
There are results regarding sphere cover density, but how can I compute the number of spherical caps knowing the density?
